# Show image with Express, instead of downloading it

Tags: node.js, image, express, nginx, download

A [simple server](https://github.com/stevage/tilelive_server) I'm working can serve images. When browsing to the image URL directly, Chrome offers to download the image, rather than just showing it in the browser. Why is that? Presumably it is something in the headers?

The relevant code is this:

```
    tilestore.getTile(req.param("z"), req.param("x"), req.param("y"), function(err, tile) {

      if (!err) {
        res.send(tile);
      } else {
        res.send("Tile rendering error: " + err + "\n");
      }

    });
```

Do I need to add something to the headers? They are currently as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 01 Sep 2014 07:22:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 37779
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
ETag: W/"9393-1937584155"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, it's easy. Just set the `content-type`:

```
  if (!err) {
    res.contentType('image/png');
    res.send(tile);
  } else {
    res.send("Tile rendering error: " + err + "\n");
  }
```

These images are always `.png`.

New headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 01 Sep 2014 07:33:22 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 37779
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
ETag: W/"9393-1937584155"
```

Comment: I still get `application/octet-stream`, any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this same problem, and found that modifying the content type alone was not enough. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936605/node-express-force-browser-to-download-file-with-custom-name), attempting to do the opposite, provided the solution. I also needed to add a `content-disposition` header:

`res.set("Content-Disposition", "inline;");`

Along with setting the correct content type, this allowed me to display my image rather than downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `svg` image files and it turned out that I had to change

`'content-type': 'image/svg'`

to

`'content-type': 'image/svg+xml'`