# node/express Force browser to download file with custom name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, download, proxy

I've built a node/express website for my university project that, after searching for an ID of a law, it shows a big table with all files in different formats and languages related with this id.
I use the module "[http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy)" to request and serve these files to client.
Nothing wrong when serving xml, xhtml, html and pdf files (every browser is able to directly view them).
I have problems with .zip and .rdf files. Files are not corrupted but they are losing the original name

- when i click on ZIP icon, it gives me the download prompt, but I'm losing the original file name (the file will be called "proxy" or "proxy.zip", different behaviors on different browsers)
- when i click on RDF icon, some browsers opens the file directly in browser, some browsers won't recognize the format, some browsers wants to download it with name "proxy")

So I discovered the HTML5 attribute "download" of the tag "a". It just solve my problem, anyway it is not supported on every version of Internet Explorer and Safari. Surfing the web I found some workarounds to add "Right click and save as..." after a div link when the page is viewed in IE or Safari, but this solution is not for me, because i'm not talking about a single link but a table full of links. And my site need to work also on mobile phones.

Is there any way to write some server-side code to force browsers to download files with a custom file name?

Here is the small piece of code of the proxy:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ ignorePath: true });

app.get('/proxy', function(req , res) {
    var file = req.query.file;
    var realurl = 'http://'+cfg.edb_opt.host+':'+cfg.edb_opt.port+cfg.edb_opt.rest+file;
    console.log('Proxy: serving '+realurl);
    proxy.web(req, res, { 'target': realurl });
});
```

All cfg* variables comes from a json configuration file to set the host, port, and starting path where files are contained.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 15):

You need to add a new header to the response object to indicate the file name and do a regular download.

```
res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=somefile.ext");
```

You could also use "inline" if instead you want the browser to try to open the file within it self, like with Chrome does with pdf files.

```
res.set("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=somefile.ext");
```

As per @Thomas suggestion, also is a good idea to include always the right  content type:

```
res.set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: to enforce a download, you may want to also add `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` to `Content-Disposition: attachment`

Answer (score 3):

In Express 4 and later, there are 2 helper functions to change the content-type and specify attachment disposition:

```js
res.type("application/octet-stream");
res.attachment("filename.ext");
```

See docs for [`type`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.type) and [`attachment`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.attachment).

Answer (score 0):

Work on your frontend code. It only works to accept custom filenames that way if you've already set  the res.setHeader in the backend like so:

```js
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;');
```

The frontend code should be manipulated to download the file with desired name, like the example below:

```js
const withoutUserId = filename.split('_')[2];
const fileExtension = withoutUserId.split('.')[1];
const parts = withoutUserId.split('-');
const filenamePart = parts.slice(0, -1).join('-');
const downloadName = `${filenamePart}.${fileExtension}`;
```

Then insert the downloadName variable in the generated blob like so:

```js
a.download = downloadName;
```