# File (PDF, JPG, PNG) download instead of opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to download document instead opening it in new tab. Files with the extension .docx download normally, but .pdf or .jpg only open in a new tab. I would like PDF and JPG files to be automatically downloaded after clicking like .docx.

HTML (cannot be changed):

```
<div *ngFor="let action of documentActions">
   <button (click)="action.makeAction(element)">
       <mat-icon>{{action.name}}</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

URL is e.q: https://web-application.com/somefile.pdf

I have tired with FileSaver (NPM intall file-saver) but still not getting downloaded only new tab open.

Ts component:

```
declare var require: any
const FileSaver = require('file-saver');
(...)
        name: 'download',
        makeAction: (elem: DocumentListItem) =>
        {
          const url = elem.documentUrl;
          const filename = elem.name;
          FileSaver.saveAs(url,filename);
        }
```

I've tired also:
`

```
 makeAction: (elem: DocumentListItem) =>
        {
          window.open( elem.documentUrl);
        }

or

   makeAction: (elem: DocumentListItem) =>
        {
          window.location.href =  elem.documentUrl;
        }
```

`
but with the same effect. Downloading docx files works in any case.
I will be grateful for help in solving the problem.

Comment: Show your server code...

Comment: It isn't very clear what library you're using , but assuming Node.js/Express, there's [javascript - node/express Force browser to download file with custom name - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936605/node-express-force-browser-to-download-file-with-custom-name)

Comment: What server code do you mean exactly? That's all the code I have for this task

Comment: On which machine is your program run on? (JavaScript code in the client browser, and not Node.js on the server? Or is this Node.js on the client machine running something to scrape a predefined website?) Why exactly can you change the JavaScript but not the HTML?

Comment: It's Angular CLI Server

Answer (score 0):

If you could construct document URLs in render phase, you could use simple HTML link with `download` attribute, like:

```
<a href="[URL]" download="[optional suggested file name]">...</a>
```

See [MDN A element download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) docs.

Comment: Existing html fragment cannot be changed. I need to handle the download in ts file

Comment: Ah, sorry, overlooked that in your question. Then hypothetically you could construct, append to body and artificially click link same element in your click handler, but I'm afraid there will be dragons.

Comment: i've tired yours solution and it gave the same effect. File is opening in new tab and isn't downloaded

Comment: hm, not very surprising, this is a error prone minefield. I did a quick test and POC and at least the most synthetic scenario worked for me (see other answer). but as soon as you break same origin or whitelisted protocol rule, or some iframes come into play or browser decides it is not secure it must break.

Comment: anyway, solution proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65807836/file-pdf-jpg-png-download-instead-of-opening-in-new-tab/65808118?noredirect=1#comment116352338_65807836 (if you manage to adjust your server to send `Content-Disposition: attachment` header) feels like the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger download from button click handler, it should be possible to mimic plain link element with download attribute click. `href` attribute of that link must either be relative in same origin as document or `blob:` or `data:` uri.

POC working in top level page (tested in current Chrome and Firefox), not working here in SO sandbox iframe:

```js
function dl(url, filename){
 var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.setAttribute('href',url);
 a.setAttribute('download', filename||'');
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.onclick = function(){setTimeout(function(){document.body.removeChild(a)},100)}
 a.click();
}
```

```html
<p>(Not working in SO sandbox iframe.)

<p><button onclick="
    dl('data:text/plain,test', 'button-download-test.txt')
    ">download text datauri</button>

<p><button onclick="
     dl(document.location.href, 'button-download-test.html')
     ">download this HTML file</button>

<p><button onclick="
    dl('./probe.png', 'button-download-test.png')
    ">download png file of same origin</button>
```